# How do you append elements to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, function, append, element

I'm making a little game based on tiles and want to make a function that adds the tiles with their tags already applied.

This is my code with tileDIV being an ID and cols being a float:

```js
function createTiles() {
    let a = document.createElement("img")
    a.src = "tiles/0.png"
    for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        tileDiv.appendChild(a)
    }
}
```

When I execute this function, nothing happens.

Comment: `tileDiv` isn't defined?

Comment: maybe document.getElementById(tileDiv).appendChild...?  Also you try to append single element cols times, you need to create each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define the `tileDiv` using DOM before calling it,

`var tileDiv = document.getElementById("tileDiv");`

also `col` is not defined, so you have to define it too for your loop function

Comment: Tnx, I used jquery for the ID, so that can indeed bee the issue

Comment: no problem as long as u have jquery source included in ur page, but i found another typo , col isn't defined too .. what is col refers to ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, titleDiv isn't defined anywhere in the script. You should define it before appending a child to it. Cols isn't defined either, that is also why it's not working.

```
function createTiles() {
let titleDiv = document.querySelector('.whateverdivis');
let a = document.createElement("img")
a.src = "tiles/0.png"
for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) { //what and WHERE is cols? 
    tileDiv.appendChild(a)
}
}
createTiles(); //call your function
```